# Calling custom events on Meteor 1.2

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to call a custom event that I made on meteor from my router controller with no success.
This is the event that I am trying to trigger:

```
Template.foo.events ({

"click button.my_event" : function (e) {
//event
}
})
```

I tried to call it using the jQuery method .trigger() like so:

```
action : function () {
$('.my_event').trigger('click button.my_event');  
}
```

Which failed.
Later I thought that the event itself needs to be made using the jQuery event layer in order to use trigger() so I tried that:

```
"click button.my_event" : $(".my_event").on("click",function (e) { 
//event
}),
```

This approach has also failed. 
Am I missing something?

Edit: I misspoke when I refereed to it as a custom event. What I really meant was a regular click event that activates a sequence of methods (like any regular event).

Answer (score 0):

You specified event type as `click`. That's why it doesn't work.

Here's working example:

```
<template name="Test">
    <button class="trigger">Trigger</button>
    <button class="test-button">Test</button>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.Test.events({
  'click .trigger': function (event, tmpl) {
    tmpl.$('.test-button').trigger('myEvent');
  },

  //custom event handler
  'myEvent .test-button': function (event, tmpl) {
    console.log('Hello, myEvent');
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I phrased my question wrong; I am using the click event to execute certain functions, which is what I meant by 'custom event'.
What I really wanted was to trigger that event programatically.

Comment: @user43825 Then you simply need to do `tmpl.$('.button.my_event').click()`

Comment: I was thinking of doing that outside of Template.Tests.events(), which I think your method applies only when I am calling it from a different event. My issue is to trigger from iron router.

Comment: @user43825 Then use same code but without `tmpl.` part